Trying to clarify how mutation is passed to offspring
In popular documentaries there is an often-used example related to mutation and natural selection. I want to clarify my understanding.
One such example is polar bears. It is being white as a result of genetic mutation and the gene is passed to offspring and they have an advantage in the snow, etc. There are many other similar examples. My question is (unless it is critical, I just want to focus on the essence of the question): Should I understand that genetic mutation made that bear white also? Or, is it the offspring that was the one that became white? Or is it the case it could be either? (Or, maybe the mutation happened in the reproduction, etc.?)

Animals are made up of cells. Each cell has a copy of DNA that contains all the patterns needed to produce the proteins that cells use to function.
Animals grow by cells dividing. In the process of division, a copy of the DNA is made. If the DNA in one cell is changed due to a copying mistake or damage (like from UV sunlight), that change only affects that one cell and any cells that come from it.
Gametes are a special type of cell used in sexual reproduction. Each contains half of the DNA of a normal cell, so when you put two together you get one cell that has a full set of DNA. That one cell, the fertilized egg, divides and the daughter cells divide etc such that all the cells of the new animal originally came from that one egg cell.
If a mutation happens in a cell that does not produce gamete cells, that mutation can't be inherited by the next generation. To have a heritable mutation, it must affect the gametes. So, most heritable mutations involve the gametes directly. Mistakes or damage in a gamete will then be in all cells of a child organism, because all cells in the child (including their gametes) will derive from the gamete's DNA.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_(biology)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredity
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamete
